# How do i Remove Windows and expand my root partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 16.04, windows-10

At first thanks for reading and obviously i am greatly thankful to you who is going to give me or show me a good way.

I am using 64bit Ubuntu-16.04 and have a 111.8GB Disk.

[image]

As you can see from above i have Ubuntu installed in extended partition **/dev/sda5** and swap in extended partition **/dev/sda6**. I have windows installed in **/dev/sda2** and System Reserved in **/dev/sda1** which are in primary partition.

Now i want to remove **/dev/sda2** and **/dev/sda1** and expand my root partition **/dev/sda5** without loosing data.

Is there any way i can do that?

And what about making the root and swap partition to primary partition without hampering system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way i can do that?

Yes. But you can not remove active partitions.

So start Ubuntu (and not Windows as you did in the image) and start up "gparted" (`sudo apt install gparted` in case you have not got it installed yet).  Mark all the Windows partitions for deleting, and execute it.

This will result in unallocated space. Next expand / to include this unallocated space, execute it.

Mind though that you can only add to a partition if the empty space is next to it. If it is not adjecent you need to add it to the one next to it and then shrink it so the empty space moves before or behind that partition and then move it in the direction you need it to go.

And you are done.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have posted the screenshot from gparted. By the way, i am concerned about the logical partition and primary ...

Comment: oh the system will sort those out for you ;-) gparted will complain when you do something ehm not smart.

Comment: Thanks. I did it successfully. But My swap and ROOT partition is in Extended Partition, can't i change it to primary or i should leave as it is ?

Comment: Just a quick query. My drives partitions are now Logical. Is there any way i can make them primary volume ?